# Back ground Image gets cut when full screen

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a full width background image.
The problem I am facing is when its full screen the bottom of the background image gets cut. And when I check the responsiveness the entire background image is shown.

How can I show the entire image when on full screen. Screen Resolution: 1366x768.

Here is the css used for background image:

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
background-image:url(img/background.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:inherit;
}
```

[Full Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuGoZ.jpg)

[Responsiveness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEKl2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

use
css attribute
 **background-size:100%;** or **background-size: cover;**

Comment: @vishpalsinh-jadejaI have tried both. It isn't working.